# Automatically change UIButtons on different ViewControllers

Tags: ios, uibutton, viewcontroller

I have UIButtons for menu on different ViewControllers. All of them look the same. 
When there is unread message or other event is happening I want to change image of menu  button on every ViewController. How it can be done without manually changing it on every ViewController?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to keep an Array of UIButtons that you can iterate over when an incoming message occurs.

```
let buttons: [UIButton] = [view1.button1, view2.button2]
... /// when event happens
for button in buttons {
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}
```

This works becuase the buttons are reference types not value types.

However this seems more like a overall design issue with how you are handling events.  I would suggest looking into [RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift) or [ReactivCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa) to bind your incoming events to your UI.

Answer (score 1):

Inherit from UIButton. In your inherited button class register a selector that will change your button image.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateButton), name: NSNotification.Name("myEventIdentifier"), object: nil)
```

Now whenever you trigger the event that you want to trap, you post a notification and it will trigger the change by calling your selector on each registered instance of your button:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("myEventIdentifier"), object: nil)
```